# JPA not persisting parent child tree

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the follow parent/child relationship, with JPA annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class DefaultProject {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<DefaultTask> tasks = new ArrayList(); ...
...
@Table(name = "task")
public class DefaultTask {
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID", nullable = false)
private DefaultProject project; ...
```

Then, in a JUnit test case, I'm trying the follow:

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin(); 
DefaultProject testProject = getDummyProject();                       
testProject.setTasks(getDummyTasks());
entityManager.persist(testProject);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
```

Saving the entities independently is working, but when saving them together gives me the follow message:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : org.demo.todo.entity.DefaultTask.project
```

Seems to me like is trying to save children first, but non-persisted parent id is causing the exception.

What's the proper way to save this relationship?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**: After enabling TRACE level at logs, I see the parent entity (DefaultProject) getting an id:

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper: 78 - Natively generated identity: 26
```

Then a few lines after when cascading to children, something goes null:

```
TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade: 80 - Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: org.demo.todo.entity.DefaultProject
TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade: 419 - Cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for collection: org.demo.todo.entity.DefaultProject.tasks
TRACE org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1: 79 - Cascading persist to : org.demo.todo.entity.DefaultTask
TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener: 501 - Transient instance of: org.demo.todo.entity.DefaultTask
TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener: 183 - Saving transient instance
TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener: 157 - Saving [org.demo.todo.entity.DefaultTask#<null>]
TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade: 80 - Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: org.demo.todo.entity.DefaultTask
TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade: 130 - Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: org.demo.todo.entity.DefaultTask
TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue: 298 - Adding an EntityIdentityInsertAction for [org.demo.todo.entity.DefaultTask] object
TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue: 248 - Executing inserts beforeQuery finding non-nullable transient entities for early insert: [EntityIdentityInsertAction[org.demo.todo.entity.DefaultTask#<null>]]
TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue: 253 - Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityIdentityInsertAction[org.demo.todo.entity.DefaultTask#<null>]]
```

Why it is not cascading the Parent entity ID?
Thanks!

Comment: can you post the complete class DefaultProject and DefaultTask ?

Comment: Check your getDummyProject() and getDummyTasks(). I think there are some attributes that's null.

Comment: I think that you must set the project in each task before persisting

Comment: Most likely you have not set both sides of the relationship. In a bi-directional relationship you must set both both sides in the in-memory model. So you must set the project for each task before persisting.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code..

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction txn = entityManager.getTransaction(); 
txn.begin();
DefaultProject testProject = getDummyProject();                       
testProject.setTasks(getDummyTasks());
entityManager.persist(testProject);
txn.commit();
entityManager.close();
```

Comment: Hi @Jobin, thanks for your response. Sadly the same exception is thrown. I added more comments to the question after enabling TRACE level at log4. Hope it helps! Thanks again!